# How to create entity formtype from a non related entity (Symfony2)?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, getter-setter, many-to-one

If you got for example the following Entities and relations:

PurchasedService * ---> 1 Service * ---> 1 ServiceCategory

how can you create a formType listing all entries from ServiceCategory within PurchasedServiceType?

As:

```
$builder
        ->add('servicecategory', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'InvoicingBundle:ServiceCategory',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('sc')
                    ->orderBy('sc.serviceCategoryName', 'ASC');
            },
        ))
```

Results in ERROR:

> Neither the property "servicecategory" nor one of the methods
>   "getServicecategory()", "isServicecategory()", "hasServicecategory()",
>   "__get()" exist and have public access in...

I would expect to call the Entity ServiceCategory directly?

Answer (score 0):

And it should. But I feel that you missed the namespace. In your case you have:

```
'class' => 'InvoicingBundle:ServiceCategory',
```

Always the InvoicingBundle is localized in some directory - you should have src/{theMissingDirectory}/InvoicingBundle/Entity/ServiceCategory , so the pattern is:

```
'class' => '{theMissingDirectory}InvoicingBundle:ServiceCategory',
```

in example:

```
'class' => 'AcmeInvoicingBundle:ServiceCategory',
```

Please try in this way and it should work.

Regards,